# On the definition of algebraic closure

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, definition, splitting-field

Let $F$ be a  field. By definition, the following are equivalent:

1. $F$ is algebraically closed.
2. Every nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$ splits over $F$.
3. Every nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$ has a root in $F$.
4. There is a subfield $K$, such that $F/K$ is algebraic and every nonconstant polynomial in $K[x]$ splits over $F$.

I want to know if the following condition also equivalent to the above:

(5) There is a subfield $K$, such that $F/K$ is algebraic and every nonconstant polynomial in $K[x]$ has a root in $F$?

If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: Note that in both (4) and (5), you need to require that $F/K$ is algebraic. If you don't, there are counterexamples such as $F=\Bbb C(x)$, $K=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: If $f$ has a root $\alpha$ in $F$, then $f=(x-\alpha)g$ where $g$ has coefficients in $F$, so by induction....

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: for (3) you can use the induction to reach (2), but since $g$ does not have coefficients in $K$, the induction does not work from (5) to (4).

Comment: @Lukas Heger: thanks, I've edited the question.

Comment: OK. (5) says $F$ contains an algebraic closure $L$ of $K$. $F/K$ algebraic implies $F/L$ algebraic. If $F$ is algebraic over an algebraically closed field, then $F=L$.

Comment: @Grerry Myerson: I cannot see why (5) says $F$ contains an algebraic closure of $K$, while (4) does imply $F$ is an algebraic closure of $K$.  (5) should be slightly weaker than (4). The problem here is that how to deduce "splitting in over $F$" from "having one root in $F$"?

Comment: OK, I give up. Any luck finding a counterexample? I can't think of an extension $F/K$  that contains a root of every polynomial with coefficients in $K$ but doesn't contain an algebraic closure of $K$.